# C# String.Replace not finding / replacing Symbol (™, ®)

Tags: c#

Basically what I'm trying to do is replace a symbol like ™, ® etc with something else but when I call

```
myString = myString.Replace("®", "something else")
```

Its doesn't do anything

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you remembering to re-assign the string?

Comment: Yes I'm later reassigning the string. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: @Killie01 thanks for some reason I didn't think the symbol was encoded and it was. The following ended up working for me name.Replace("\u00AE", "<sup>\u00AE</sup>")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try myString.Replace("\u00A9", "else");
you have to escape the ©

Comment: Hey man you were right! I needed the encoded version of the symbol. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: oh 00A9 = the copyright mark, i thought it was what you wanted,
00AE is indeed the r thingy

Answer (score 6):

When you use `String.Replace` you create a new string. It is a very common mistake to believe the the supplied string is modified. However, strings in .NET are immutable and cannot be modified.

You have to call it like this:

```
myString = myString.Replace("®", "something else");
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your mistake is in calling Replace without assigning the result to anything.

without seeing your code is difficult to guess, but something like this should work:

```
myString = myString.Replace("®", "something else");
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be likely that C# does not like the literal registered symbol. I would suggest trying to replace the character by using a character code, using either the integral value, hex, or unicode.

Below is an example using the integral value of the character ®.

```
string originalString = "whatever®";
string stuff = "something else";
char registered = (char)174;
string replacedString = originalString.Replace(registered, stuff);
```

ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `string.Replace` returns a new string, so you need to re-assign it

```
myString = myString.Replace("®", "something else");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Unicode characters to replace this symbols.

```
        string x = "® ™ dwdd2";
        string y = x.Replace('\u00AE', 'X');
```

It's working ;-)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

And a list of Charakters:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Thats trash invalidsyntax... I'm replacing ® with the char X... maybe you should read msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx

Comment: I ended up using 'code'name = name.Replace("\u00AE", "<sup>\u00AE</sup>");'code'

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
var myString = "Hello world ®, will this work?";
var result = myString.Replace("®", "something else");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

results in:

> Hello world something else, will this work?

You can see it [run here](http://rextester.com/rundotnet?code=HFO15984).

Does your original string really contain that character or does it contain something like an html entity: `&reg;` or `&#174;` or other "encoded" version of that character?