# C# string.Replace doesn't work

Tags: c#, string, replace

**Basically our Problem is:
We can't replace a string like this: 10003*
But we can replace a string like this: 10003**

we want to replace a part of a string that looks like this: 10003*
This is our Code:

```
string text = sr2.ReadToEnd();
sr2.Close();
while (loop != lstTxt.Items.Count)
{
    string SelectedItem = lstTxt.SelectedItem.ToString() + "*";

    text = text.Replace(SelectedItem, "tietze111");


    if (lstTxt.SelectedIndex < lstTxt.Items.Count - 1)
        lstTxt.SelectedIndex++;
    loop++;

}

sw2.Write(text);
```

But it doesn't work. When we leave out the * in the part to replace, it works. But we have to replace the * too. Do you know what we have to change?

It works when we use this:

```
string text = sr2.ReadToEnd();
sr2.Close();
while (loop != lstTxt.Items.Count)
{
    string SelectedItem = lstTxt.SelectedItem.ToString(); // changed

    text = text.Replace(SelectedItem, "tietze111");


    if (lstTxt.SelectedIndex < lstTxt.Items.Count - 1)
        lstTxt.SelectedIndex++;
    loop++;

}

sw2.Write(text);
```

--
    using (var sr2 = new StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + @"\website\Dehler 22 ET.htm", Encoding.Default))
                {

```
                using (var sw2 = new StreamWriter(tempFile, true, Encoding.Default))
```

We are using this because the file is still in ASCII. Maybe that is the problem.
How do we solve this?

Comment: A System.String is a sequence of unicode characters, so when you read the file it is converted to unicode. Debug and  set a breakpoint, check that the value is what it should be. Perhaps decode it to byte array, and see if data or the substitutionkeys are not what you think... ('*' is a character that is defined in ASCII encoding.)

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Fix the following line,

```
string SelectedItem = lstTxt.SelectedItem.Value;
```

You are taking the item and not the value.

Comment: Basically our Problem is:
 - We can't replace a string like this: 10003*
 - But we can replace a string like this: 10003

Comment: Could it be a problem of encoding ? You might be mixing UTF-8 and ASCII characters.

Comment: Did you copy the valur from something like a Word document, in that case it's most definitely a problem of mixing the encodings. IN which case you simply need to remove and write the asterik again. In other case : From where are you getting this value that's 10003* ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
"[\*]"
```

Or

```
@"[*]"
```

Comment: not sure if this'll work or not.. just something I found online

Answer (score 0):

The `String.Replace(String,String)` method doesn't do anything special with any characters. There is a character in your id that you are trying to replace is not the same as the one you are trying to match on. I would try copying the astrisk from the data source into your code and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: have you set a breakpoint in your code to see what is actually stored in `text` before you try the replacement?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem * is encoded in some other type. The Unicode value for asterisk U+002A

You could try this. Note Char.MinValue is technically a null value since you cannot have a blank Char.

In your case: `lstTxt.SelectedItem.ToString() + '\u002A'.ToString();`

If that doesn't work try removing (using different encoded values for *) to make sure you can actually find it in the string.

```
SomeString.Replace('\u002A', Char.MinValue);
```

OR

```
SomeString.Replace('\u002A'.ToString(), String.Empty);
```

I've ran into issues like this before and it ends up being a trial and error kind of thing until you get it right. Similar problem I had last summer [C# String.Replace not finding / replacing Symbol (™, ®)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178695/c-sharp-string-replace-not-finding-replacing-symbol)