# String.Replace working in VB but not C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

The following VB code works correctly and does not flag up any errors.

```
strLine = strLine.Replace(strLine.LastIndexOf(","), "")
```

However the same C# code doesn't:

```
strLine = strLine.Replace(strLine.LastIndexOf(","), "");
```

This will not compile as it says

> The best overloaded method for 'string.Replace(string,string)' has some invalid arguements.

How come this works in VB but not in C#? and how do I fix this?

I thought it might be similar to [C# string.Replace doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389432/c-sharp-string-replace-doesnt-work) but it implies that that code will infact complile.

Likewise with other string.Replace questions: [string.Replace (or other string modification) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948978/string-replace-not-working), it appears they will infact compile, whereas mine will not.

Comment: I'm curious - did you read the documentation on MSDN for the method you're trying to use?

Comment: `The following VB code removes all the "," seperators` - no, it removes all occurences of the textual representation of the position of the last comma in the string of data. E.g., all occurences of `"42"`.

Comment: @J.Steen - I was looking back at some of my schoolwork (which is all in VB) and just tried a straight copy/paste/modify to C#. I'm reading about it just now.

Comment: @GSerg - I'll edit that comment. I wasn't sure how it worked, I just knew it worked.

Comment: This is why I always try to use Option Strict On when using VB.NET

Comment: @Ewan It *compiled*, that's entirely different from working.  That VB is rather non-sensical and almost certainly isn't doing what you want it to do.  VB code is much more likely to compile and just not work when given nonsensical code; C# just won't compile until you give it sensible code.

Comment: @Servy - VB also doesn't have to compile as it's interpretted at runtime?

Comment: @Ewan False.  VB is not an interpreted language.  It just doesn't do as much verification at compile time, which is very different from not being a compiled langauge at all.  VBScript is interpreted, but while it looks similar and acts similar in many ways, it's an entirely different language.

Comment: @Servy - I'm beginning to think it's that teacher then ...

Comment: Ewan, as an aside, you really should look at documentation before posting. I'm pretty surprised you got any upvotes at all -- your question is easily answered by just Googling `c# string.replace`. First thing that comes up is documentation showing the parameters *with* examples.

Comment: @tnw: The question isn't how to do string replacement in C#, it's *"How come this works in VB but not in C#?"*, and the answer is that VB will quietly coerce numbers into strings.  @Ewan wouldn't have learned that by googling for `c# string.replace`.

Comment: @RichieHindle Yes he would. My answer is more or less directly from the documentation that I linked (which I found and referenced by Googling exactly that). Are you seriously arguing that he shouldn't bother to look at documentation?

Comment: @tnw: Of course he should read the documentation, but it doesn't answer the question *"How come this works in VB?"*. Your answer doesn't answer that question either (but it does solve his problem, of course). pipTheGeek's comment answers the VB question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`LastIndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1wdsy8fy.aspx) returns an *integer*, not a string. [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) takes `string, string` as parameters, you're passing it `int, string`, hence the exception `The best overloaded method for 'string.Replace(string,string)' has some invalid arguements.`

If you're just looking to remove all `,` use this:

```
strLine = strLine.Replace(",", "");
```

Based on your code, you *may* be only wanting to replace the last instance of `,` so try this if that's what you want:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(strLine);
sb[strLine.LastIndexOf(",")] = "";
strLine = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Beat me to it.
VB works because it will attempt to convert the number to a string for you.  If you add Option Strict On to the top of the file then you should see it fail to compile with a similar error to the C# error.

Comment: This answer is correct.  It's just VB trying to implicitly cast objects for you under the hood.  C# is better about not letting you get away with that.

Comment: @tnw - Thanks! I added the option strict on in my VB and got bombarded with thousands of errors in my entire school code. Goes to show they don't teach you anything in school!

Comment: @Ewan See my edit -- If you wanted to only replace the last instance of `,` then I accounted for that

Answer (score 1):

Reading [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx), I'm amazed that the first example works at all. string.Replace should receive either a couple of chars or a couple of strings, not an integer and then a string. Pheraps the VB version is converting the integer to its char representation automatically?

Comment: The project could have option strict off, allowing late-binding to silently convert the integer to a string.

Comment: True. Hadn't thought of that. I'm still skeptic as to it working correctly, as the OP said. More like it's *building* correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
string.Replace("," , "");
```

Comment: Might want to add some details *why* that will work, not just a code dump

Comment: I was on the toilet looking at stack on my tiny phone. Code dump was all I could offer.

Comment: That's fine, this is more a FYI: short answers sometimes get placed on a review queue as "low quality", that's where I found yours. So it's important to add details for the OP as well as to make sure your answer doesn't get marked low quality.

Answer (score 0):

In c# the String.Replace's first parameter must be either char or string, but you are using a integer(string.LastIndexOf returns a integer).
Why not just use:

```
strLine = strLine.Replace(',', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# `LastIndexOf` returns an `int`, but `Replace` expects a `string` or a `char` as the first argument. I don't know VB to explain why your code works, but I can explain that in C# you can't pass an `integer` where a `string` or a `char` is expected.

In C#, this will do what you want:

```
strLine = strLine.Replace(',', '');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String.Remove`

```
strLine = strLine.Remove(strLine.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
```